# Representing an Entity Type with two parent types in an Entity-Relationship Diagram?

Tags: database-design, entity, entity-relationship, database-schema

I have entity type called **STUDENT** which has two sub-types: **GRADUATE**, and **UNDERGRADUATE**. Easy enough.

Now, I (*presumably based on specifications*) also have another entity type called **RESEARCH ASSISTANT**, which is defined as being a student (thus inheriting STUDENT's attributes)... but the specification is ambiguous as to whether RESEARCH ASSISTANT is either a graduate or an undergraduate.

Assuming that a research assistant can be either case, how do I represent this in an entity relationship diagram? In examples, the notation represents a child type by drawing it within the parent... But what if the child has two different parents?

If I simply sub-type STUDENT, then it becomes ambiguous as to whether the research assistant is graduated or not... So do I draw two different entities for RESEARCH ASSISTANT (one within graduate and the other within undergraduate)? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think it in another way. Instead of making a **research assistant** inherit from **student**, you can make it into a relationship with those (what in OOP is known as [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance))

In the diagram, keep **student**, **graduate** and **undergraduate** just as you have right now, and add a "one to zero or one" relationship from **student** to **research assistant**. When that relation is present, the student (graduate, undergraduate or whatever) will also be an assistant, but when that relation is missing he'll be student only.

Comment: Alright. Two questions... 

1. I thought that relations were supposed to be strictly "verbs", such as "Complies with", or "Submits documentation". What would I label this relationship? Maybe "Is A"?

2. If I draw this relationship from **student**, then would the diagram still indicate that **undergraduate** and **graduate** can be members of **research assistant** as well?

Comment: In this case, that relation would be a "does research" and will contain the extra information required for research-specific activities.
I would not assume that all relationships are always "verbs", but they can also link to additional data, such as "have a....".
**Graduate** and **undergraduate** are now indirectly related with **research assistant**, it's directly implied that they are **students**, and student can be in turn researchers. It will end as a 3-table JOIN to build that association.

Comment: Perfect, this really cleared things up for me! Thanks, and sorry for the late reply!